# avoiding array index outof bound exception while splitting string

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I am trying to read a file and split the line of string line by line. This is the sample String in file

```
Decorative Platters--------Home & Kitchen->Home & DÃ©cor->Home DÃ©cor Accents
Hookah--------Watches & Jewellery->Fashion Jewellery->Bangles
hookah--------
```

in this case third line don't have anything after the dots.

```
private static void getCategoriesFromFileAndMAtch()  {
    try {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mapping_log"));
        String eachLine;
        while((eachLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String input1, input2, tempString;
            input1=eachLine.split("--------")[0];
            tempString=eachLine.split("--------")[1];
            if(!(eachLine.split("--------")[1].isEmpty()))
            {
                tempString=eachLine.split("--------")[1].split("::=>")[0];
                System.out.println(input1+"   "+tempString);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }

}
```

because of value of [1] is empty I am getting the exception and program stops . How can I avoid that? I am checking its empty or not in if loop. Is that not enough?

Answer (score 2):

When you write the following line, you are assuming that the element exists, but it does not exist at all in your case, and the `if` statement itself blows up with the Exception.

```
if(!(eachLine.split("--------")[1].isEmpty()))
```

Instead, check the length of the return value of `split()`.

```
if(eachLine.split("--------").length > 1)
```

Comment: I think you want `if(eachLine.split("--------").length > 1)` there -- `length` is a property of an array, not a method. (Too small a fix to submit an edit.)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Do not do tempString = eachLine.split("--------"); multiple time, each time this is performed, it splits the line over and over again (costly opeartion). So, Always, split once and try to re-use the result as mentioned in the following sample.
2. In cases where the array length is not known, use array.length to find it out and add the appropriate conditions.

Sample:

```
String input1, input2, tempString;
String [] parts = eachLine.split("--------");
input1 = parts[0];

if (parts.length > 1) {
    input2 = parts[0];
    tempString=input2.split("::=>")[0];
    System.out.println(input1 + "   " + tempString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the third case, `eachLine.split("--------")` will return an array with length 1 so when you access that array with index 1, ie
    `eachLine.split("--------")[1]` it gives an exception. You can fist check if the array returned by the split function is greater than 1

```
if(eachLine.split("--------").length > 1 && !(eachLine.split("--------")[1].isEmpty()))
{
 tempString=eachLine.split("--------")[1].split("::=>")[0];
 System.out.println(input1+"   "+tempString);
}
```